# Ho do I use a query getByTestId from react-testing-library properly?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my components with react-testing library.

Some of my components are good with getByTestId query but others aren't.

**Examlpe:
SideBar component code**

```
export const SideBar: FC<SideBarPropsInterface> = ({ className }) => {
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false)

    const handleToggle = (): void => {
        setCollapsed((prev) => !prev)
    }

    const classNameChecked = className ?? ''

    return (
        <div
            data-testid="sidebar"
            className={classNames(
                styles.sideBar,
                { [styles.collapsed]: collapsed },
                [classNameChecked]
            )}
        >
            <button onClick={handleToggle}>toggle</button>
            <div className={styles.switchers}>
                <ThemeSwitcher />
                <LangSwitcher />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Test for SideBar**

```
describe('SideBar', () => {
    test('render', () => {
        render(<SideBar/>)
        screen.debug()
        expect(screen.getByTestId('sidebar')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

**Error**

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="sidebar"]

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

As you can see test renders just div without attributes.

But my other components are good with it. Like Button component

**Button component code**

```
export const Button: FC<ButtonPropsInterface> = ({
    children,
    className,
    theme,
    ...otherProps
}) => {
    
    const classNameChecked = className ?? ''

    return (
        <button
            data-testid="special"
            className={classNames(styles.button, {}, [
                classNameChecked,
                styles[theme as ThemeButton]
            ])}
            {...otherProps}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

**Test for Button**

```
describe('Button', () => {
    test('render', () => {
        render(<Button>test</Button>)
        screen.debug()
        expect(screen.getByTestId('special')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

**Passed(screen.debug)**

```
  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <button
          class="button undefined"
          data-testid="special"
        >
          test
        </button>
      </div>
    </body>
```

**Question:** what am I doing wrong? I need my SideBar component to pass the test with getByTestId query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution. If you have child components inside your parent component, you need to mock them manually.

In my case I have `<LangSwitcher/>` and `<ThemeSwitchers/>` inside `<SideBar/>`

RTL doesn't see them until I mock

```
jest.mock("widgets/LangSwitcher")
jest.mock("widgets/ThemeSwitcher")

describe('SideBar', () => {
    test('render', () => {
        render(<SideBar/>)
        screen.debug()
        expect(screen.getByTestId('sidebar')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```